# Запуск debug на другом ПК

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой запуска экзешника на другом устройстве. У меня есть проект, где происходит подключение к бд и производятся манипуляции с ней. Однако, при запуске дебага возникает ошибка связанная с отсутствием коннекта к БД. Подскажите, в чем заключается проблема? P.S. если запустить полностью проект в студии на другом устройстве, тогда запуск через дебаг снова возможен.

Comment: Хотя бы указали какая БД: *.MDB, *.ACCDB, SQL Server, SQL CE.

Comment: Использую бд из VS - MS SQL LocalDB

Comment: LocalDB вроде необходимо бинарник устанавливать, и работает только на localhost